# how do I get the thumbnails to display the larger original image on hover?

Tags: html, css, image-gallery

I have created an un-ordered list for an image gallery. On hover it currently displays the thumb nail, how to I adjust my code to get it to display the orginal larger imager?

A portion of my current code:

```css
.gallery {
    cursor: default;
    list-style: none;
}
.gallery a {
    cursor: default;
}
.gallery a .preview {
    display: none;
}
.gallery a:hover .preview {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -33px;
    left: -45px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.gallery img {
    background: #fff;
    border-color: #aaa #ccc #ddd #bbb;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    color: inherit;
    padding: 2px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100px;
    height: 75px;
}
.gallery li {
    background: #eee;
    border-color: #ddd #bbb #aaa #ccc;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    color: inherit;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
}
.gallery .preview {
    border-color: #000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pictures">
  <h1>S.O.S - Image Gallery</h1>
  <ul class="gallery">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="thumb/thumb2.jpg" alt="Newcastle PSA workplace group at the IRC." />
        <img src="thumb/thumb2.jpg" alt="Newcastle PSA workplace group at the IRC." class="preview" />
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provider your code in a snippet that runs so we can easily see the behaviour

Comment: Wouldnt you just want to change the `<img src="thumb/thumb2.jpg" alt="Newcastle PSA workplace group at the IRC." />
` from a "thumb2.jpg" to your original sized image?

Comment: Change the 2nd image to your full img path: <li><a href="#"><img src="thumb/thumb2.jpg" alt="Newcastle PSA workplace group at the IRC." /><img src="thumb/thumb2.jpg" alt="Newcastle PSA workplace group at the IRC." class="preview" /></a>

Comment: @BrennanMcdonald I tried that, replaced it in the first then the second but neither option worked. Figured I was missing something else

Comment: @rsn I tried changing the first and the second, but neither worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It already works, you just need to swap out the second image: https://jsfiddle.net/3q29wvyv/1/.

```css
.gallery {
         cursor: default;
         list-style: none;
         }

   .gallery a {
         cursor: default;
         }

   .gallery a .preview
         {
          display: none;
         }

   .gallery a:hover .preview
         {
         display: block;
         position: absolute;
         top: -33px;
         left: -45px;
         z-index: 1;
         } 

   .gallery img {
         background: #fff;
         border-color: #aaa #ccc #ddd #bbb;
         border-style: solid;
         border-width: 1px;
         color: inherit;
         padding: 2px;
         vertical-align: top;
         width: 100px;
         height: 75px;
         }

   .gallery li
         {
         background: #eee;
         border-color: #ddd #bbb #aaa #ccc;
         border-style: solid;
         border-width: 1px;
         color: inherit;
         display: inline;
         float: left;
         margin: 3px;
         padding: 5px;
         position: relative;
         }

   .gallery .preview
         {
         border-color: #000;
         width: 200px;
         height: 150px;
         }
```

```html
<div class="pictures">
   <h1>S.O.S - Image Gallery</h1>
   <ul class="gallery">
   <li><a href="#"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/Thumbnail1.jpg" alt="Newcastle PSA workplace group at the IRC." /><img src="https://www.trophycupcakes.com/sites/default/files/styles/standard_cupcake_detail/public/cupcakes/cupcake-red-velvet.jpg?itok=Zyu04GZ6" alt="Newcastle PSA workplace group at the IRC." class="preview" /></a>
   </li>
   </ul>
   </div>
```

Comment: ok thankyou I will try it again, maybe it just work in brackets preview

Comment: thanks, it works, I also adjusted the sizing in the css, i think that was blocking my images from getting larger than they were

Answer (score 0):

Just write the filename of the large image into the second `img` tag (the one with `class="preview"`)